# Missing Data imputation on one continuos column which depends on another feature and which does make sense only when such feature is positive

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-imputation, feature-engineering, feature-scaling

For each row (open contract) of my dataset, I have got a certain number of orders.
I have created some features related to such orders; let's take for instance the average and the std deviation of the intervals in terms of time.

**PROBLEM**: when I have 0 orders, both the average and the intervals are NaN.
Moreover, whenever I have 1 order, Python clearly puts the std deviation to 0 -because having only one value- but that's conceptually wrong, since corresponding to the case in which I have N intervals of the same lenght.
I have to handle these two exceptions, considering that together samples with 0 or 1 orders are 50% of my dataset.

**MY SOLUTION**: I thought about putting a value out of scale (thus, negative): at the moment I put -100 to both average and std dev when I have 0 orders and -50 (only to std dev) when 1 order, as in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Aup.png).
The reason, or at least what I'm trying to achieve, is to have a continuos variable and a model able to discriminate the negative values, understanding that the latter just refer to an exception.

**QUESTION**: The value with whom I fill such situations, strongly influences the scaling (reminding that they are 50% of my data). In [Fig 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZYMr.png) two different scaling: above filling with -2 and -1, below resulting scaling using -100 and -50.

 **Models which are scale variant, such as SVM or Neural Networks, are thus very affected by this choice.** Can you please tell me how to appropriately choose a reasonable out of scale value, or another way to handle these situations?